# Set a minimum space above and below displayed math

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-spacing

**NOTE:** This question is specifically about adding vertical space that increases to compensate for tall symbols. Thus, it is not a duplicate of [How can I change the whitespace above and below math displays?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47773/484).

I'm trying to revise my university's thesis class to produce spacing with displayed math that works a little bit better with double spacing (which is required). What I have in mind is this:

1. The distance above and below a displayed math environment should be the same as the distance between the top of a typical line of text and the bottom of the preceeding line. In particular, symbols that go even slightly above the "usual" height should lower the baseline.
2. Within a multiline displayed math environment such as `align` or `eqnarray`, the distance between baselines should be the same as `\baselineskip` unless this would cause the distance between symbols to go below (say) `6pt`, in which case the baseline should be lowered so that the distance between symbols is exactly `8pt`.

For instance, in the document below, the space between the two `Z=` lines needs to be increased, and the space below the bottom math line needs to be increased even more.

[image]

How can this be accomplished? (By changing settings in the preamble; I'm writing a document class, not playing with specific pieces of math.)

Here's what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%Code that belongs in the class file:
\makeatletter
    \RequirePackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
%        \lineskiplimit=0pt%
%        \lineskip=\dimexpr\baselineskip-\f@size pt\relax%
        \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
        \jot=0pt%
    }
\makeatother

%Code that belongs in the preamble:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
f \colon X &\to Y \\
x &\mapsto y \\
Z &= \left\lfloor\frac{\mathcal E \hat{} \otimes \mathcal E}{g\mathcal E \hat{} \otimes \mathcal E} \right\rfloor \\
Z &= \left\lfloor\frac{\mathcal E \hat{} \otimes \mathcal E}{g\mathcal E \hat{} \otimes \mathcal E} \right\rfloor
\end{align*}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The idea is commendable, the task is hopeless: double spacing should be banned as a crime against typography.

Comment: Which task? Developing a more aesthetic standard, or implementing the specific standard I've suggested?

Comment: The task I referred to is implementing your specifications.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with @egreg (especially) that typesetting 10/20pt is not a card of the good typography. I have a special and extensive notice about this bad practise in theses mentioned in my [templates for theses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/178693#178693). But the problem from TeXnical point of view is very interesting and it seems to be non-trivial. This is the reason why I tried something...

We need to switch between two modes:

- normal paragraph, where `\lineskiplimit=0pt` is good choice, because the in-text sum or integral can be occur here, but the main preference is to keep the equidistant baselineskip here. May be the negative `\lineskiplimit` can be tried here too because the rare in-text tall objects would be probably not be exactly above one another.
- display math, where `\lineskiplimit=10pt`, `\lineskip=10pt` is good choice to solve the desired task.

The most difficult problems are at the border between these two modes, especially below display formula: the first line of the next paragraph is set by zero `\lineskiplimit` which needs to insert the strut into this first line. That is solved by `\aftergroup` and `\belowdislayABCD` macros. Moreover, we test if the paragraph ends here or not.

Additionally, I solved the following problems:

- I destruct the strut named `\strut@` locally in display because it interferes badly with positive `\lineskiplimit` setting.
- I set right value of the `\strutbox` in order for the array environment to work properly. Notice that this is a bug of the `setspace/doublespacing` package. If we do none other changes (only use this package), the matrices generated by `\begin`/`\end{array}` are bad.
- I set `\above`/`below*skip` to zero. This yelds the grid for lines in paragraph and for the display lines (if there aren't tall). You can set a positive value here if you need to add additional space.

My experiment is without any warranty. This is not a definitive solution but only the material for further study. It is very probable that some problems occur with normal documents and that these changes interfere with plenty of LaTeX packages.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%Code that belongs in the class file:
\makeatletter
    \RequirePackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt
        \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
        \abovedisplayskip=0pt
        \belowdisplayskip=0pt
        \jot=0pt
        \everydisplay={\lineskiplimit=10pt \lineskip=10pt \normallineskiplimit=10pt
           \let\strut@=\relax
           \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height8pt depth4pt width0pt}
           \aftergroup\belowdisplayA}
    }
\makeatother

\def\belowdisplayA {\afterassignment\belowdisplayB \let\tmp= }
\def\belowdisplayB {\ifx\tmp\spacetoken \expandafter \belowdisplayC
                    \else \expandafter\belowdisplayD \fi}
\def\belowdisplayC {\afterassignment\belowdisplayD \let\tmp= }
\def\belowdisplayD {\raise20pt\vbox{}\ifx\tmp\par \vskip-\baselineskip \fi \tmp}
\edef\tmp{\let\noexpand\spacetoken= \space}\tmp

%Code that belongs in the preamble:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
%Z &= \left\lfloor\frac{\mathcal E \hat{} \otimes \mathcal E}{g\mathcal E
%\hat{} \otimes \mathcal E} \right\rfloor \\
f \colon X &\to Y \\
x &\mapsto y \\
Z &= \left\lfloor\frac{\mathcal E \hat{} \otimes \mathcal E}{g\mathcal E
\hat{} \otimes \mathcal E} \right\rfloor \\
Z &= \left\lfloor\frac{\mathcal E \hat{} \otimes \mathcal E}{g\mathcal E
\hat{} \otimes \mathcal E} \right\rfloor
\end{align*}
This is a display formula with matrix. This is a display formula with matrix.
$$
  a=b, \quad
  {1\over2}
  \left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f
  \end{array}\right)
$$
This is a simple display formula. This is a simple display formula.
$$
  a=b
$$
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: 10/20 math typesetting]

Comment: They said it couldn't be done....

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188568/484

Comment: While I am obviously quite impressed with this answer, I also feel obliged to point out that the mechanism for detecting a following paragraph works for the tex primitive `$$`, but not for the latex version `\]` or for `\end{align*}`.

Comment: I have written that this is only experiment for further study. LaTeX brings troubles very often... We need to read the `\]` and `end{align*}` internals and do something more...

Comment: Mysteriously, `\def\belowdisplayA{\vskip 10pt\noindent}` seems to do the correct thing for both `\]` and `\end{align*}`, although it fails for `$$` (which is considered bad practice when using latex).