# Spacing between consecutive displayed equations

Tags: spacing, equations, lyx

I'm trying to adjust the spacing between several display equations, without having to put them in AMS align environment. I inserted several display equations in a row, each creating its own new line, but I would like to adjust the spacing of said lines. Here's an example of LaTeX source:

```
We can quickly calculate:
\[
a=12
\]
\[
b=9
\]
\[
c=19.2
\]
Which results in results
```

I can't figure out how to set the spacing between them. I am using Lyx as my editor, so ideally a solution that involves changing the Lyx document setting would be the best. However, I'm fine with adding a preamble latex code to adjust that spacing.

Thank you so much for all your help; any input is appreciated!

Comment: never use one `\[` after another. (or any display math environment) The spacing between them will always be wrong .

Comment: You don't need to use `align` if you do not want alignment, you could use `gather`

Comment: lyx provides the ability to use the multi-line display structures from `amsmath` (including `align` and `gather` mentioned by david carlisle).  documentation for those structures can be found in [this manual](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)

Comment: If gather doesn't satisfy, use \vspace or \raisebox and \parbox.

Comment: To change the whitespace around math displays in general, see Q & A: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47773/how-can-i-change-the-whitespace-above-and-below-math-displays

Comment: @JohnKormylo The first choice to adjust line spacing would be to add an optional argument to the line end characters `\\[2ex]` in the gather environment.  I don't have lyx, so don't know whether this is a menu option or ERT.