# Too big vertical spacing between equations

Tags: spacing, equations, vertical

My vertical spacing between multiple equations are too big, how can I reduce it? each equation most have an individual label.

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{mitthesis}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in, twoside, openright]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %ramme rundt bilder
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[super,square]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font=small, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}                    % For lange tabeller
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{color,soul} %highlighting
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}   %lister
\setlist{noitemsep}     %ingen vertical spacing i liste
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %kjemi-formler
\usepackage{tabularx} %hindre for brede tabeller
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} %fjern automatiske bindestreker
\usepackage{mathtools} %matte

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}   %footnote
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e} %tabeller (flush)
\usepackage[]{bm}
\usepackage{perpage}

\MakePerPage{footnote}
```

Here's the code:

```
This is some text before the equations:
\begin{equation}
    a = b
    \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    b = c
    \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   c = r
   \label{eq:3}
\end{equation}

The spacing is fine if I only have one equation:

\begin{equation}
    x = y
\end{equation}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text...\\
```

And the pdf:

[image]

Comment: For one, get rid of the blank lines between adjacent equations in your source code.  Better still, use `align` or a similar `amsmath` environment.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: Just get rid of the blank lines between the equations and it it works fine.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz No you should not have consecutive equation environments either

Comment: @DavidCarlisle to keep the equations together?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz spacing is wrong (but not as bad as when you have a paragraph break)  if you follow `$$` by `$$` and `equation` does nothing to fix it.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213755/spacing-between-consecutive-displayed-equations which shows your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you load `mathtools`, use the `gather` environment:

```
\begin{gather}
    a = b
    \label{eq:1}\\
    b = c
    \label{eq:2}\\
   c = r
   \label{eq:3}
\end{gather}
```

or `align` if you want… some alignment:

```
\begin{align}
    a & = b
    \label{eq:1}\\
    b & = c + d + e\label{eq:2}\\
   c & = r
   \label{eq:3}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Tsk, tsk!  Just because the OP doesn't provide a full MWE, doesn't mean you should follow suit.  We know you know better.

Comment: I'm in hurry at the moment… Anyway, the O.P. already loads the relevant package :o)